# Trying to display post data onto a display page using datatables and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

so I'm currently working on a forum-like project that involves users to be able to submit a post to a database and then for the post title to be displayed on a datatable. The hyperlink of  title will re-direct the user to the postDisplay page based from the postId that is submitted through the url.

The project is an asp.net web-form that uses Entity Framework.

The following code is the Post.cs Class

```
 public class Post
    {
        //The post ID
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int postId { get; set; }
        // Foreign key to customer
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string postTitle { get; set; }
        public string postBody { get; set; }
        public string postDepartment { get; set; }
        public string postCategory { get; set; }
        public bool postAnonymous { get; set; }
        public int postLikes { get; set; }
        public int postDislikes { get; set; }
        public DateTime postDate { get; set; } 
    }
```

The code below is responsible for submitting the post to the db

```
protected void AddPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationUserManager _userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = _userManager.FindByName<ApplicationUser, string>(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);


            var department = "";
            using (var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                department = _dbContext.Departments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.deptId == user.deptId).deptName;
            }


            Post newPost = new Post()
            {
                postTitle = inputTitle.Text,
                postBody = inputBody.Text,
                postCategory = inputCategory.SelectedValue,
                postAnonymous = Convert.ToBoolean(Int32.Parse(inputAnonymous.SelectedValue)),
                Id = user.Id,
                postDepartment = department,
                postDate = DateTime.Now,
            };

            using (var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                _dbContext.Posts.Add(newPost);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            //Display success message and clear the form.
            string message = "Your suggestion has been submitted successfully!";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            script += "'; }";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }
```

The code below is reponsible for creating the DataTable that views the post titles while hyperlinking the postId to the postDisplay Page

```
<div  class="jumbotron">

    <table class="display" id="postsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Date</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
  <br />

</div>
 <asp:HiddenField id="deptName" runat="server"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">



     $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#postsTable') .DataTable({
            pageLength: "5",
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/posts/GetDatatables",
                type: "GET",

                dataType: "json",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

                        return '<a href="/PostDisplay/LoadPost?postId="' + row.postId + '">' + row.postTitle+'</a>';

                    }
                },
                {data: "postCategory"},
                {data: "postDate"},

            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now for the final part where the error seems to stumble, the postDisplay page starts with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int postId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["postId"]);


        }
```

According to the debugger, the postId is requested correctly and is parsed to an int, but when the value is then displayed as int postId, it doesn't actually carry the number with it in the url?

<-------------------------EDIT-------------------------->

The following error is displayed from the line of code above

```
"Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not realy clear to me... What do you mean by "the postId is requested correctly" and what do you mean by 'value is then displayed as int postId' (where do you display)?

Comment: @Thor  So every time a post is created, it generates a postId. So I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks on a post title that's displayed, they will be redirected to the postDisplay page that views the specific one they selected.  The jquery code is supposed to send the postId value on the URL when the hyperlink is clicked, and then the postDisplay page is supposed to get the postId from the URL and the display the relevant data that's stored in the database for that postId.